# HTML5でinputタグはformタグで囲う必要はありますか？

Tags: html, html5

検索して下記は見つけましたが、HTML5に関する言及はありませんでした。
[inputタグはformタグで必ず囲む必要がありますか？ - HTML | 教えて！goo](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4292882.html)

送信する必要がなければ`<form>`で囲う必要はないと考えております。

また、`<input>`タグの内容が変わったこときに、Ajax通信をするという処理であれば、送信処理はformではなくAjaxが行うので、`<form>`で囲う必要はないのかなと考えています。

仕様的には決まっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 11, accepted):

『HTML5日本語訳』 [4.10.5 input要素](http://momdo.github.io/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)

> この要素を使用できるコンテキスト：
>   　フレージングコンテンツが期待される場所

とのみ書かれており、特に「`form`ブロックの内側」という規定は見当たりません。

Answer (score 13):

HTML4と5の仕様上は、`input`要素などのコントロールは`form`要素内になければならない、とは定められていませんので、裸のコントロールがあってもかまいません。

(古いのはよくわかりません）

HTML5ではさらにフォーム部品が`form`属性を持つことで、`form`要素の外にあっても`form`要素と関連づけることができるようになりました。

Answer (score 5):

`<form>`タグは、入力・送信フォームを作る際に使用します。 `<form>～</form>`の間に、 `<input>`・ `<select>`・ `<textarea>`等のタグで、 一行テキストボックス・サブミットボタン・ラジオボタン・チェックボックス・セレクトボックス・テキストボックス等のフォーム部品を配置します。

送信する必要がなければ`<form>`で囲う必要はありません。

Ajax通信をする場合、`<form>`で囲う必要もありません。